# No events intraday data from Firebase analytics in bigquery

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

Summary: What i want is get the data that my apps push to Firebase analytics. I've seen that this is possible in realtime with the analytics intraday dataset. I've linked my firebase with bigquery and ticked the apps on so that they share data.
My firebase has billing set so i have the blaze billing settings.

Problem: There is no dataset of analytics. i only see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZC2i.png), there is no dataset of the realtime data called "intraday".

Edit: Right now i have the event data from the past days. but still no realtime data from the intraday dataset

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: are you using BigQuery sandbox? "Crashlytics BigQuery streaming export is not available for BigQuery sandbox."  https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/bigquery-export#streaming-export